# How to read PDFs on Linux so the white margin around the page is automatically cropped?

Tags: linux, pdf, pdf-reader

I have another device, an eInk ebook reader (Onyx Boox), that has this wonderful feature, "auto-crop", that auto-detects the white margins in pdf (with a given degree of "aggression"), and zooms out it.

Sometimes, at night, I prefer to use my notebook to read ebooks. This option would make the experience much better, but so far I can't find this feature in any PDF software I've tried.

How do you read PDFs that "auto-crop" the white margins on a Linux system?

I'm not interested in permanently removing the white space out of PDFs; just hiding it for sake of a reading session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, and not all kinds of PDFs (that at least is my experience: the closest I got was, if memory serves, FoxIt Reader). I usually go a more radical way and crop the PDFs at the source using tools such as [PDFquench](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/pdf-page-cropping-tool-ubuntu-linux/), or [PDFcrop](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/); I too used to read them on a Onyx A60 (also tried annotating them and reading back with Okular), before switching to a rooted PRS-T1.

It would perhaps be possible to create a script to get a PDF, make a cropped copy of it, and run a plain old PDF viewer on the copy, deleting it upon closure.

Comment: That's bad news. I'll wait a moment and then I'll try to make such script. It shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: I've tried myself, and the linked PDFcrop utility seems to have problems with zero-sized BBoxes. The pdfcrop I use turned out to be a script by one Heiko Oberdiek, with the `--pagesize` and `--margins` options. Note that, depending on the PDF, the output size may increase considerably.

Comment: I understand, that the PDFcrop doesn't provide option for "fuziness" of the cropping (like the pdf reader for Onyx does), so if the PDF have a header/footer far away from the text, it still always includes it, right?

Comment: Yes... I've been bitten by the script bug :-), so I am too being experimenting with cropping (I usually did it visually, but having a script catches my fancy). `pdftk` allows uncompressing the PDF and exposing the `MediaBox`, now I'm thinking of counting all the objects with their coordinates, and build a "heat map"...

Comment: I've been playing with the iText library in Java. I've now a nifty little framework to trim a PDF in (mostly) any way I decide. Could I perhaps interest you in being a beta tester? :-)

Comment: @Isemi yes, please! :-) But I know virtually nothing about Java (I know C++ and Python though).

Answer (score 2):

I use **Okular** on Ubuntu. It has a simple option to trim margins - exactly what you are looking for :-)

Comment: I have tested Okular and it has a "Trim View" on menu View/ Trim View / Trim margins that really works, but, unfortunately, it doesn't export that view to another PDF file.